# Update employee manager using employeeid

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So, I am working on a project that will update some employee information weekly as required by audit based on our HR system.  The only unique matching field that I have from HR is employeeID (for both users and managers).  I have no problem getting Get-ADUser to pull up the employee and update these fields, but now I also need to update the employee's manager using their employee ID.  I'm not sure how to get powershell to convert that manager employee ID into their UPN or some other method to pull their info.  Here is my code

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Users = Import-csv "C:\Users\my.stuff\stuff\TitlePowershell.csv"

foreach($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeID -eq $user.employeeID} 
        | Set-ADUser -replace @{description=$User.description; title=$User.title; manager=$user.ManagerID}
}
```

What can I add to get manager to update from their employee id?

Comment: @marc_s was kind enough to update my code which is great, and it runs without error, but I don't actually see the manager update in AD.

Comment: If you're looking at ADUC, you may need to refresh to see changes.

Comment: @AndrewDavis - even when I check it in powershell Manager is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Manager` attribute of a user contains the `DistinguishedName` of that user.
Since apparently in your CSV file, you have the `EmployeeID` of that manager, you need to do some extra work to get the DN

Try

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Users = Import-csv "C:\Users\my.stuff\stuff\TitlePowershell.csv"

foreach($User in $Users) {
    # get the user object for the manager
    $usr = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.employeeID)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($usr) {
        # get the user object for the manager
        $mgr = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.ManagerID)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($mgr) {
            $usr | Set-ADUser -Replace @{Description = $User.description; Title = $User.title; Manager = $mgr.DistinguishedName}
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "No manager found with EmployeeID $($user.ManagerID)"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No user found with EmployeeID $($user.employeeID)"
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion I would make is if there are a lot of employees then you will end up with many employees who share a manager, which leads to repeat calls to AD for the same user object. If there was a hashtable for the managers, you could check if the manager record is already there rather than performing another `Get-ADUser` call. It really depends on the scale of OP's task.